# Simple implementation of 2D convolution neural network (CNN)

Tags: cnn

I am looking for a good reference implementation (code) of 2D CNN (convolution neural network) using simple math operations instead of framework's high level tensor operation. This is for inference only. Many open source code implementations out are quite complex and utilize high level operations.

Comment: How about [this](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/04/building-convolutional-neural-network-numpy-scratch.html)? Is there a specific language you are aiming for?

Comment: Thank you. The reference implementation could be any language. My target language is Rust. Based on your link's title I've found following articles: 

1) https://towardsdatascience.com/convolutional-neural-networks-from-the-ground-up-c67bb41454e1 

2) https://datascience-enthusiast.com/DL/Convolution_model_Step_by_Stepv2.html

3) https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-convolutional-neural-networks-from-scratch-f1e3bfc3e2de